# drupal 7 profle2 in single page with standart

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, profile

how i can add profile2 form in one page with drupal user profile form?
i try this hook, but it's don't work for me :(

```
    function MY_MODULE_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if (($type = profile2_get_types('profile')) && $type->userCategory) {
    if (empty($form_state['profiles'])) {
      $profile = profile2_load_by_user($form['#user'], 'profile');
      if (empty($profile)) {
        $profile = profile_create(array('type' => 'profile', 'uid' => $form['#user']->uid));
      }
      $form_state['profiles'][$profile->type] = $profile;
    }
    profile2_attach_form($form, $form_state);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://drupal.org/project/account_profile en the D7 version does de trick.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean when you edit the profile or when your user register with the site? 
If you mean former, it won't! This is a different entity and so it always have a tab on your profile edit page. IF you have multiple profile associated with your account, each them will have a separate tab. If you want to completely avoid this, use the 'manage fields' page on 'account settings' on admin > configuration page.